# Is this surface rational -- Magma says no, but I have rational parametrization?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f(x,y,z)$ be the degree $6$ polynomial:

```
x^6 + 6*x^5 + 15*x^4 - 3*x^2*y^2 + 20*x^3 - 18*x^2*y - 6*x*y^2 - 2*y^3 - 12*x^2 - 36*x*y - 21*y^2 + 4*z^2 - 48*x - 72*y - 80
```

I am interested if the surface $f(x,y,z)=0$ is rational.

We have $f(u+v-1,u^2+v^2-3,u^3-v^3)=0$, which is rational
parametrization.

I believe this is sufficient condition the surface to be rational
by definition of rational variety.

Magma claims it is not rational.

> Is it rational or not?

Magma online code http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/:

```
K<x,y,z,t>:=ProjectiveSpace(Rationals(),3);
p:=x^6 + 6*x^5*t + 15*x^4*t^2 - 3*x^2*y^2*t^2 + 20*x^3*t^3 - 18*x^2*y*t^3 - 6*x*y^2*t^3 - 2*y^3*t^3 - 12*x^2*t^4 - 36*x*y*t^4 - 21*y^2*t^4 + 4*z^2*t^4 - 48*x*t^5 - 72*y*t^5 - 80*t^6;
S:=Surface(K,p);

IsRational(S : CheckADE := true); //return "false"
```

Comment: "I believe this is sufficient condition the surface to be rational
by definition of rational variety." No, not by definition but by a theorem of Castelnuovo, which implies  that for a surface "unirational" is the same  as "rational" (in characteristic zero).

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Thank you. So even if my reasoning is wrong, I still suppose it is rational, which implies Magma bug?

Comment: Did you check that the parametrization is correct with Magma?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Not yet, but I checked it with Sage and Maple.

Comment: That certainly suffices: I can't imagine both systems making a mistake on such a trivial calculation. One possible  explanation could be that $f$ is not irreducible and that the parametrization only describes one irreducible component of the surface $f=0$. Did you check the irreducibility of $f$ ?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Certainly. It is irreducible over the rationals according to both Sage and Maple and absolutely irreducible according to Maple (don't know how to check this in sage).

Comment: A smooth surface in $\mathbb P^3$ of degree $\geq 4$ is guaranteed to be non rational. Did you check smoothness of the closure  in $\mathbb P^3$ (which has degree six) of your affine surface?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg No, I didn't check this. Why should I check it?

Comment: Because smooothness would guarantee that your surface is not rational, as I explained in my previous comment.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Due to ignorance I don't know how to compute it. But am still sceptical that it matters in this case.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: it is not smooth --- in fact it has a 1-dimensional locus of singularities. (I used Macaulay2 to check this.) joro: what do you mean you are "sceptical that it matters"? As Georges says, if it were smooth, it would be _guaranteed_ to be nonrational. (It isn't, but that's not the point here.) It is very off-putting to read comments like this.

Comment: @Relapsarian So likely this is technical bug in Magma and not in paper they tried to implement?

Comment: Joro: yes, this seems to be a bug in Magma. I am a little surprised, because http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/1356#15017 claims explcitly to be able to work with arbitrary surfaces in $\mathbf P^3$.

Comment: @Relapsarian To my surprise Magma does **some** singular rational surfaces right...